# If $A$ and $B$ are two points on a line from the origin where $OA\cdot OB=1$, and $P$ is a point on the unit sphere, then $PA : PB = \text{constant}$?

Tags: geometry

> If $O$ is the centre of a sphere of radius unity and $A$ and $B$ are two points in a line with $O$ such that $OA\cdot OB=1$, and if $P$ is a variable point on the sphere, show that $PA : PB = \text{constant}$

I have tried, but I am confused.  Must $A$ and $B$ be on boundary of sphere?  Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

The points $A$ and $B$ do not need to be on the boundary of a sphere. The problem tells you that $A$ and $B$ are two points on a line with $O$ such that $OA \cdot OB = 1$. This does not require $OA$ and $OB$ to be on the sphere. For instance, we could have $OA = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $OB = 2$. Then, $A$ and $B$ are definitely not on the sphere, since their distance from $O$ isn't $1$.

The problem should have also mentioned that $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of the line with respect to $O$, i.e. $O$ is not in between $A$ and $B$. Without this assumption, $\tfrac{PA}{PB}$ is not constant.

Anyway, here are some initial steps to get you started.

Draw a coordinate system such that point $O$ is the origin and points $A$ and $B$ are on the positive $x$ axis. Since $OA \cdot OB = 1$, you know that $OA = \tfrac{1}{a}$ and $OB = a$ for some number $a > 0$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are on the positive $x$ axis, we have $A = (\tfrac{1}{a},0,0)$ and $B = (a,0,0)$. Next, let $P = (x,y,z)$ be a point on the unit sphere (this means that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$).

Now, compute $\dfrac{PA}{PB}$ using the distance formula, and simplify as much as possible. You should get an answer that does not have $x,y,z$ in it.